# Error in Android Jni when trying to get a field Id

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, field

I want to get the array of signatures, which is a field of PackageInfo.

My C++ code is (LOGD is a macro for logging):

```
jclass PackageInfoClass = pEnv->FindClass("android/content/pm/PackageInfo");
if(PackageInfoClass == NULL) {
    LOGD("class PackageInfoClass not found");
    abort();
}
LOGD("class PackageInfoClass found");

jfieldID SignaturesFieldID = pEnv->GetFieldID(PackageInfoClass, "signatures",
        "[Landroid.content.pm.Signature;");
if(SignaturesFieldID == NULL) {
    LOGD("field SignaturesFieldID not found");
    abort();
}
LOGD("field SignaturesFieldID found");
```

On my log I get the message "field SignaturesFieldID not found"

Comment: use `[Landoid/content/pm/Signature;`   instead of   `[Landroid.content.pm.Signature;`

Comment: Thanks! that did it.